# How to test an spring bean annotated by @ConditionalOnExpression using @SpringbootTest whose `classes` are specified

Tags: spring-boot-test

Let's assume a bean

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("#{'xxx1'.equals(environment['prefix.property_one']) && 'xxx2'.equals(environment['prefix.property_two'])}")
public class ABean{
//...
}
```

and a test class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"prefix.property_one:'xxx1'","prefix.property_two:'xxx2'"})
@SpringBootTest(classes = {Abean.class})
//@SpringBootTest
public class Tester{
}
```

In test class, I just want to load ABean to avoid heavy initialization of whole spring envirnment.

But when I started my test class. Spring complains `Property or field 'environment' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public or not valid?`

But when I disable SpringBootTest's classes parameters. Everything goes right. So I tried to add `MockEnvironment.class` or `Environment` at head of classes parameters.It does not work at all. And  I tried to use ConditionalOnProperty but it can not express and logic.

What should I do to test ABean without loading other bean ?